# Logitech g-hub buttons g7 and g8 not programmable

Tags: logitech-mouse

I can't assign any keys to the g7 and g8 buttons, and pressing them does nothing... any idea on how to fix this? I already updated / reinstalled g-hub. thanks

[image: ghub]

Comment: Go into the Logitech G Hub and check the onboard memory option. If Off, turn it to On. If On, turn it Off/On a few times. If the problem persists, reinstall the software.